# Loading texture causes access violation

Tags: c, opengl, memory

I'm trying to load a height map into my program and it causes an access violation error and I don't know why.

```
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    int width, height, nr_channels;
    unsigned char *height_map = stbi_load("textures/noise.jpg", &width, &height, &nr_channels, 0);
    if (height_map)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, height_map);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        set_int(shader_program, "height_map", 0);
        printf("Loaded a height map that's %i in width and %i in height", width, height);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to load texture");
    }
    stbi_image_free(height_map);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the texture has 4 channels (`GL_RGBA`)? What is returned for `nr_channels`?

Comment: The texture has white, gray, and black. Nr_channels returns how many colors there are so I will try setting `GL_RGB` and see how that goes.

Comment: So apparently me setting the `nr_channels` to `GL_RED` doesn't make the program seg fault, but, it reports that it's unable to open the file.

Comment: `nr_channels` is an output parameter like "width" and "height". It tells you how many channels the texture image actually has. The value returned is (1, 2, 3 or 4)

Comment: I fixed this by turning the `nr_channels` to `GL_RED`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assume that the texture has 4 channels. `nr_channels` is an integral output parameter like `width` and `height`. It tells you how many channels the texture image actually has. The returned value is 1, 2, 3 or 4. So if `nr_channels` is equal to 1, the texture has 1 channel and you have to use the `GL_RED` format. 3 means `GL_RGB` and 4 means `GL_RGBA`. The last parameter of "stbi_load" is an input parameter that allows you to force the desired number of channels. Pass 4 to the las argument to get a texture image with 4 color channels (`GL_RGBA`):

<s>`unsigned char *height_map = stbi_load("textures/noise.jpg", &width, &height, &nr_channels, 0);`</s>

```cpp
unsigned char *height_map = stbi_load("textures/noise.jpg",
                                      &width, &height, &nr_channels, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `nr_channels` from `GL_RGBA` to `GL_RED` fixes this.